# I used one coat of paint. The room looks good. Do I still need a second coat?

Tags: painting

I'm using Sherwin Williams paint & primer (2 in 1).

Comment: If you don't add a second coat, the paint police will barge in during dinner one of these nights and arrest you.  :)

Comment: Seriously, though, after it is completely dry, look at it in different light, look at it from angles with sunlight on it. If it looks evenly covered and you're happy with it, there's no point adding another coat if you don't want to. If parts of it seem thin, add another coat!